# Swift adding relative force to a physics body

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, physics, game-physics, physics-engine

I have a question.
I am busy with a game (for educative purposes for myself) in Swift for OSX.
I am trying to create a car which can be turned around and can be moved.
I use this update function:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    self.moveMentForward()
    self.moveMentSteer()

    var point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.car.size.width, y: self.car.size.height/2)
    var force2: CGVector = CGVector(dx: self.directionForwardForce!, dy: 0)

    self.car.physicsBody?.applyForce(force2, atPoint: point)
    self.car.physicsBody?.applyAngularImpulse(CGFloat(self.directionSteerForce!))
}
```

But the applyForce is always in the X and Y direction, so the car will only move to the left or right.
But i want the car to be moved to different directions, like up and down or in a different direction.
So actually the force has to be applied always to the back of the car, like in this images:
[image: force 1]

[image: force 2]

Is this possible with Swift and if so, how is this possible?
Thank you very much already.

Comment: This is a question about SpriteKit. What does it have to do with Swift (the language)?

Comment: I am sorry, I chose the wrong subject maybe, but its important to say it has to be in swift, because I cannot write objective-C and 99% of the solutions is in objective-C code

Comment: what about `CGVector(dx: F*cos(a), dy: F*sin(a))` for GCS? `F` is the force and `a` is the angle or take your forward vector and rotate it by angle `a` for LCS (local/global coordinate system)

Comment: up/down equals x/y movement in a 2d physics/game engine, you can not literally "raise" the car with 2d physics

Comment: Yeah, the comment of @Spektre worked, but then you will get really weird situations like the car will move horizontal and i guess that's really hard to fix

Comment: When i looked around the internet i saw this:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsVehicle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014183-CH1-SW2 \n I am having only 1 problem, how can i put this car physics inside an SKSpriteNode?

Comment: SCNPhysicsVehicle is for 3D scene kit not sprite kit.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This following is a simple car simulation. The car moves at a fixed speed. Turn the car by tapping either side of the screen.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        // Set the properties of the sprite
        sprite.size = CGSizeMake(64, 64);
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.frame), CGRectGetMidY(view.frame))
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
        sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        self.addChild(sprite)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            var action:SKAction
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if (location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)) {
                action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI/45.0), duration: 1.0)
            }
            else {
                action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-CGFloat(M_PI/45.0), duration: 1.0)
            }
            sprite.runAction(action)
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        let r = 15.0
        // Get the direction of the car (in radians)
        let theta = Double(sprite.zRotation)+M_PI_2
        // Convert angle and speed to vector components
        let dx = CGFloat(r * cos(theta))
        let dy = CGFloat(r * sin(theta))
        // Set velocity of the car
        sprite.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx, dy)
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to account for the rotation of the image by adding PI/2 to the zRotation.

Comment: Good general idea, but note that you can avoid doing the conversion math yourself by using [`convertPoint:toNode:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/convertPoint:toNode:) or similar methods.

Comment: @rickster which conversion are you referring to?

Comment: Converting `r` and `sprite.zRotation + M_PI_2` to a Cartesian vector in scene space is equivalent to taking the point `{-r, 0}` in `sprite`'s local space and converting it to scene space. Ultimately it's the same math, but you're probably better off letting SpriteKit do it for you.